# Model Serving with sklearn and gRPC

Tags: python, scikit-learn, thread-safety, grpc, grpc-python

Say I have an trained RandomForestClassifier model from sklearn.  We're using gRPC to serve that model and provide predictions in real-time in a high traffic situation.  From what I understand, gRPC can support multiple threads run concurrently.  Can they all simultaneously make calls to RF's **predict** method without running into concurrency issues?  Is sklearn's **predict** thread-safe?

If this isn't the case, it sounds like you'd have to load individual copies of the model in each worker thread.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about sklearn specifically, but in general, gRPC is thread-safe, and it's fine to make many concurrent calls to the same method.